# R why does do.call not match a direct calculation?

Tags: r, do.call

In the process of doing something more complicated, I've found the following: 
If I use do.call converting a numeric vector to a list, I am getting a different value from the applied function and I'm not sure why.

```
x <- rnorm(30)
median(x) # -0.01192347

# does not match:
do.call("median",as.list(x))  # -1.912244
```

Why?

Note: I'm trying to run various functions using a vector of function names. This works with do.call, but only if I get the correct output from do.call.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm sure someone will explain _why_, but `do.call(median,list(x = x))` will return the value you expect.

Comment: Ah, of course, `as.list` is splitting the vector into a list of individual elements, and so then `do.call()` just grabs the first element to pass to `median`.

Comment: Thank you!  That works and explains a bit what was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So `do.call` expects the `args` argument to be a list of arguments, so technically we'd want to pass `list(x = x)`:

```
> set.seed(123)
> x <- rnorm(10)
> median(x)
[1] -0.07983455
> do.call(median,list(x = x))
[1] -0.07983455
> do.call(median,as.list(x))
[1] -0.5604756
```

Calling `as.list` on the vector `x` turns it into a list of length 10, as though you were going to call `median` and pass it 10 separate arguments. But really, we're passing just one, `x`. So in the end it just grabs the first element of the vector and passes that to the argument `x`.

Comment: You might also look into why you're not getting an error with the `as.list(x)` version. If I do this: `do.call(stats::median, as.list(x))` I get an `unused arguments` error. You seem to be using a different definition of `median` that does something else with those other 29 args, and that difference may cause you further bugs later.

Comment: @Chris Interesting, I'm not getting the unused argument error. I suspect the extra values are being swallowed by `...`.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, that was on "bugs in your hair", probably just version differences.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  :-)